# performance of coefficient-wise array operations of the eigen library with mkl backend

Tags: c++, performance, intel-mkl, eigen3

I am porting a Matlab algorithm with lots of coefficient-wise array operations to C++, which look like this example, but are often much more complex:

```
Eigen::Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tx2(12);
tx2 << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
Eigen::Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tx1(12);
tx1 << 7,8,9,10,11,12;
Eigen::Array<double, Dynamic, 1> x = (tx1 + tx2) / 2;
```

The C++ code turned out to be significantly slower than Matlab (around 20%). So in a next step I tried to turn on the Intel MKL implementation of Eigen, which did nothing for the performance, like literally no improvement. Is it possible that MKL does not improve coefficient-wise vector operations? Is there a way to test if I linked MKL sucessfully? Are there faster alternatives to the Eigen::vector classes?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I`m using VS 2013 on an i7-3820 running win7 64bit.
Longer Example would be:

```
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> ts = (k2 / (6 * b.pow(3)) + k / b - b / 2) - (k2 / (6 * a.pow(3)) + k / a - a / 2);
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tp1 = -2 * r2*(b - a)/ (rp.pow(2));
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tp2 = -2 * r2*rp*log(b / a) / rm2;
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tp3 = r2*(b.pow(-1) - a.pow (-1)) / 2;
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tp4 = 16 * r2.pow(2)*(r2.pow(2) + 1)*log((2 * rp*b - rm2) / (2 * rp*a - rm2)) / (rp.pow(3)*rm2);
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tp5 = 16 * r2.pow(3)*((2 * rp*b - rm2).pow(-1) - (2 * rp*a - rm2).pow(-1)) / rp.pow(3);
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> tp = tp1 + tp2 + tp3 + tp4 + tp5;
    Array<double, Dynamic, 1> f = (ts + tp) / (2 * ds*ds);
```

relevant part of CMakeLists

```
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    target_link_libraries(MK ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib mkl_core_dll.lib libiomp5md.lib)
```

and I've only defined EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL so far.

Comment: Please provide the following: platform; compiler flags; a slightly longer example of coefficient-wise vector operations; any relevant defines.

Comment: Also, what CPU are you targeting? (AVX, AVX2.0, etc.)

Comment: its an i7-3820, so AVX is supported, but not AVX2

Comment: Did you [let Eigen know](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html) it should use MKL. Start with defining `EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL`.

Comment: yes, I've put the define just above the Eigen include

Comment: What version of MKL?

Comment: On last thing I can think of is that not all SSE options are enabled in VS. You can test by using `std::cout << Eigen::SimdInstructionSetsInUse() << "\n";` to see what is enabled. To manually enable SSE > 2, define `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE4_2`, `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE4_1`, `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSSE3`, `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE3`. P.S., the current release of Eigen does not use AVX.

Comment: Eigen::SimdInstructionSetsInUse() << "\n"; returns SSE and SSE2 so I guess these are already enabled. I thought MKL uses AVX, is that not so? And are you aware of a library that might be faster than eigen?

Comment: MKL will use whatever it wants. Eigen only uses [part](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html#TopicUsingIntelMKL_SupportedFeatures) of the MKL functions.

Comment: "Is it possible that MKL does not improve coefficient-wise vector operations?" - MATLAB uses Intel MKL behind the scenes for most of its operations.

Comment: @IKavanagh Doesn't that mean my C++ code should be at least as fast as MATLAB, if I implemented MKL correctly? Is there a comprehensive List of which Eigen functions functions benefit from MKL?

Comment: @user2160180 You mean "linked MKL correctly", not "implemented MKL correctly". The [link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html#TopicUsingIntelMKL_SupportedFeatures) I mentioned above lists the MKL functions that Eigen uses. `pow()` is listed in the table there.

Comment: @AviGinsburg yes, thats of course what I meant. So pow() is supported and used quite frequently in my code, makes it even more strange that my runtime doesn't improve. In the link it is mentioned that "Dynamic or large enough objects" are supported. Does this include the Arrays I've been using? Also, the list does not include the */+- operators, which make up the majority of my code, and the corresponding mkl functions (e.g. v?Mul )are missing. Maybe they're just not supported, and I should use v?Mul directly...

Comment: @user2160180 What are the approximate lengths of your arrays?

Comment: 99% of them are length 2101

Answer (score 6):

Replace calls to `pow(2)`, `pow(3)`, and the likes to `square()`, `cube()`. Same for `pow(-1)` which is advantageously replaced by a division. I hope MatLab is able to do all these kind of optimizations for you, but in C++, only working at the compiler level would make such compile-time optimizations possible.

Comment: Wow, that brought down my runtime a lot! (1100 ms down to 480 ms). Thx a lot!

Answer (score 4):

In short, if you have Intel's C++ compiler, use that.

I constructed a MCVE to test a few of the assumptions made here. We want to test

1. Linking of MKL
2. Eigen's vectorization of

   1. Addition
   2. Multiplication
   3. `pow(double)`
3. Compilers' effects

with Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <iostream>

//#define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE

// SSE>2 doesn't affect these tests
#ifndef EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE // Not needed with Intel C++ Compiler XE 15.0
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE4_2
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE4_1
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSSE3
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE3
#endif

#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL 

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

#include <mkl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::cout << Eigen::SimdInstructionSetsInUse() << "\n";

    int sz = 32 * 1024 * 1024;

    double dummyAdd, dummyMult, dummyPow;

    // Quick test to show linking worked
    {
        float a[16] = {23.54f};
        float r[16] = {0.f};
        float b = 2.f;

        vsPowx(4, a, b, r);
        std::cout << r[0] << "\n";
    }

    Eigen::ArrayXd v1 = Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(sz);
    Eigen::ArrayXd v2 = Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(sz);
    Eigen::ArrayXd v3 = Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(sz);

    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    {
        v3 = v1 + v2;
        dummyAdd = v3.sum();
    }
    auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Total Time (addition) " << dummyAdd << " = " <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count()
        << " milliseconds.\n";

    startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    {
        v1 = v3 * v2;   // 
        dummyMult = v1.sum();
    }
    endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Total Time (multiplication) " << dummyMult << " = " <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count()
        << " milliseconds.\n";

    startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    {
        v3 = v1.pow(3.5);   // 
        dummyPow = v3.sum();
    }
    endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Total Time (pow(3.5)) " << dummyPow << " = " <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count()
        << " milliseconds.\n";

    return 0;

}
```

I then compiled using cl (VS's compiler) and Intel C++ Compiler XE 15.0, both with and without EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE and EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL. I compiled *without* omp for these tests. I got (i5 3470) interesting results. For cl, I saw no difference whether or not MKL was linked, but a slight

> None
>   554.132
>   Total Time (addition) -2006.37 = 130 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (multiplication) 1.11832e+007 = 137 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (pow(3.5)) -1.#IND = 1730 milliseconds.

and

> SSE, SSE2
>   554.132
>   Total Time (addition) -689.959 = 86 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (multiplication) 1.1175e+007 = 87 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (pow(3.5)) -1.#IND = 1695 milliseconds.

So we see that the addition and multiplication appear to be vectorized, but `pow` is not affected by MKL.

The Intel compiler showed similar results in behavior, but better with `pow`.

> None
>   554.132
>   Total Time (addition) 7594.98 = 96 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (multiplication) 1.11818e+007 = 94 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (pow(3.5)) -1.#IND = 921 milliseconds.

and

> SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2
>   554.132
>   Total Time (addition) -1953.37 = 87 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (multiplication) 1.11796e+007 = 87 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (pow(3.5)) -1.#IND = 838 milliseconds.

without EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL and

> SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2
>   554.132
>   Total Time (addition) 1512.55 = 87 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (multiplication) 1.11759e+007 = 89 milliseconds.
>   Total Time (pow(3.5)) -1.#IND = 843 milliseconds.

with EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL.

I can understand Intel's compilers tendency to super optimize code up to the point of matching MKL's performance. I would have expected to see some difference in the cl performance. Bottom line, use the Intel C++ compiler if you need better performance.

Comment: Thx for the MCVE. I compiled it myself and added a comparison pow(2) and square(). The performance gain is quite large (1567ms vs 68 ms). However, as you have shown there is no difference with EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL  defined, even with the square function, which is supposed to be supported. I'll gladly try the Intel compiler, but I have only experience with cmake+VS. Can you point me to a quick tutorial on how to use the compiler with all my includes? (mainly vtk, boost and eigen)